# how to read csv file in talend with specific escape and enclose character?

Tags: talend

I'm getting some problem to read csv file in talend 6.0 version.

I have some csv files and some files having format like this

```
KeyDate      TRANSACTIONID  PLACE

"2015-09-18" "633631"      "DELHI" 

"2015-09-18" "633631"      "DELHI"
```

And in some its like this

```
KeyDate      TRANSACTIONID  PLACE

"18/09/2015" "633632"      "PUNE" 

"18/09/2015" "633632"      "PUNE"
```

I set Escape Character : ""
Enclose Character :  "\""

And set "yyyy-MM-dd" in tschemacompliance cos in output I only need files  not having date format like this "yyyy-MM-dd". But compliance component is passing all type of files having both date formats.

How can I get files not having date format like "yyyy-MM-dd" through reject row with correct escape and enclose character?

Please correct where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what is your requirement here..is rejecting file a requirement or just loading data a requirement. if you are interested in loading all data, then you can read the keyDate column in csv as String type and then transform this inside talend in tjavarow or tMap ..here you can catch exception while transforming keyDate from STring to Date in both format..this way you dont have to worry about reject. Even if you want to move data into different flows based on date format you can do that too via tJavaRow or tMap..

Comment: @garpitmzn actually first am trying to store all csv files in different folder who doesnt have date format "yyyy-MM-dd" using tschemacompliance but no one is rejecting. I have tried all escape and enclose character as well and set up the date format as well in string in tschema

Comment: thats what i am trying to understand why you need reject ..are these invalid records, as to me it looks that these are also valid dates and should be processed. I suggest if you want to reject data you should explore tJavarow or Tmap where for each row you can parse every column in schema and take decision how to handle that row.